# why post method doesn't refresh the page in the action method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, http, asp.net-core-mvc

I know the post action method below is anti-pattern, but still I assume to see a new page with Name being set to null. But when I click the submit button, the page is not reloaded and I still see the old name displayed, is this a browser thing or asp.net core framework thing?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private IRepository repository;
   public HomeController(IRepository repo)
   {
      repository = repo;
   }

   // ...

   public IActionResult Create()  // create a Employer that has a name in the browser
   {
      return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Create(Employee model)
   {
      model.Name = "";   // <----------------set it to null so I expect to see the Name being empty in the reponse
      return View(model);  
   }
}

// view file, Create.cshtml:

@model Employee
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Employee";
}

<h2>Create Employee</h2>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id"></label>
        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DOB"></label>
        <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Role"></label>
        <select asp-for="Role" class="form-control" asp-items="@new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Role)))"></select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Firstly, a get method to invoke the Create() action method and fill some data:

[image]

After clicking submit button, the page still shows the original name where I exepct to see a empty name since I modify it in the post action method

[image]

so why the name still exists after the second request?

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: @viveknuna no error code at all

Comment: Can you see in the network tab that is it really calling the Create method?

Comment: @viveknuna I have attached some screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why the name still exists after the second request?

Well, altough, you have `rebind` your `model property value`. However, your `current model state` still remain unchanged. Therefore, you are getting the older value even after the `form resubmission`. To overcome this issue, please try following code snippet:

**Solution:**

You have clear your current model state by using [`ModelState.Clear();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.clear?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method before assigning the new value.
So, your create method should be as bellow:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Employee model)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            model.Name = "";  
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Note:** Rest of the code will remain unchanged.

**Output:**

[image]

`ModelState.Clear();` wwill resolve your issue completely.